# asmack vs tigase xmpp library

Tags: android, asmack, tigase

I am working in android chat app.I would like to use one of the following xmpp client (Tigase, Asmack). But I don't know which one to use . Can you tell me which one is better based on performance and features available in library?

Comment: XEP-0198 is a important feature which Tigase xmpp client supports, specially for android client implementations. As i checked asmack still doesn't support it. But only issue with tigase is lack of documentations

Answer (score 0):

For me Asmack worked just fine. I've had no problems with it whatsoever, also smack has a very nice documentation with a lot of examples. Don't know much about Tigase, all I can say is that I had a lot of fun playing around with smack.

Comment: I already used asmack in my app. But it struggle in voice chat implementation using jingle. And Tigase support caching of server data.So I need any other information regarding voice chat implementation using tigase.